# 2D Array of JButtons not getting clientProperty right

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton

### Introduction

I am trying to create a cheeckers game in which I initialize an 8x8 array, fill it with white and black buttons to create the game table

then I fill in the 1,2 || 5,6 row with white and black pawns with a loop, in which I name them, as BLACK and WHITE pawns, get their index and put a clientProperty about their color.

### Problem

Now comes the tricky part, in the same loop in which I create the pawns, text of buttons gets filled ok (1,2 || 5,6 row)  but **the color as clientProperty gets filled to completely different index**.

You can only acess the 0,1  and 4,5 row others throw a NPE.

### Code demonstrating the problem

This is the loop that fills in the pawns..

```
for (int pos = 0; pos < bSquares.length; pos++) {
    for (int line = 0; line < bSquares[pos].length; line++) {
        if(line == 1 || line ==2){
                bSquares[pos][line].putClientProperty("pawnColor", "black");      
                bSquares[pos][line].setText("BLACK PAWN ");
                bSquares[pos][line].putClientProperty("pos", pos);
                bSquares[pos][line].putClientProperty("line", line);
                bSquares[pos][line].putClientProperty("type", "normal");
                bSquares[pos][line].addActionListener(new select());
        }
        else if(line == 5 || line == 6){
                        bSquares[pos][line].putClientProperty("pawnColor", "white");
                bSquares[pos][line].setText("WHITE PAWN");
                bSquares[pos][line].putClientProperty("pos", pos);
                bSquares[pos][line].putClientProperty("line", line);
                bSquares[pos][line].putClientProperty("type", "normal");
                bSquares[pos][line].addActionListener(new select());
                bSquares[pos][line].putClientProperty("locos", "normal");

        }
            }
```

### Additional Resources

And this is the whole class for further reading if needed 
http://pastebin.com/PswKMgT5

Comment: Rename `ii` and `jj` to `row` and `col` and your code will be a lot more readable.

Comment: Shouldn't `bSquares[jj][ii] = b;` be `bSquares[ii][jj] = b;`?  It's what you're using elsewhere (although for an 8X8 square I doubt it makes a difference).

Comment: Yes you are right about the index swap  it wont make any difference tho, as you said

Comment: There is a little better structured version of the code which is also more readable, hope it makes it easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

There may be other errors in your code, but as the comment alluded to, you are sometimes referencing `bSquares` like `bSquares[pos][line]` and at other times as `bSquares[line][pos]`.  Either way will work, but you need to be consistent.

Change this line from:

```
final String nos = bSquares[line][pos + 1].getClientProperty("pawnColor").toString();
```

to

```
final String nos = bSquares[pos + 1][line].getClientProperty("pawnColor").toString();
```

and I think you'll get what you want (or at least fix one error).

Comment: Yes this solved a part of the issue, except of the last one that throws an error cause it goes beyond the index size I guess